# A few question about hamachi and what it will work with

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi

When using hamachi do both users have to have hamachi? and also should this strategy work on macs?
I've already tried making a server and i didn't work so this is my last option to play with my friends.
Looking forward to reply

Comment: If you can't create a server, yo can use some free server hosts that will let you and your friends play together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible that your friends can join your Hamachi server when they don't have Hamachi?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211373/is-it-possible-that-your-friends-can-join-your-hamachi-server-when-they-dont-ha).

Answer (score 1):

Hamachi is creating a virtual LAN network for users.

Yes, both users need to use Hamachi.

Back at 2008, me and my friends were using it. Since then, I've never used. A user creates a room at Hamachi, other users join that room. We were using it with Counter Strike, Half-Life and The Lord of the Rings Battle for Middle Earth 2. As soon as we joined the same room at Hamachi, we could play the game normally through LAN game menu.